# How to make sure that a Maria DB docker image is started in Azure pipelin?

Tags: azure, docker, mariadb, pipeline

I am using Maria DB docker image for integration tests, that run in an Azure pipeline. The database is actually a dump from an existing database, which i put in a docker image.
The problem is that when i start the container via the following commands:

```
docker pull <some_azure_repository>/databasedump:<tag_number>
docker run -d --publish 3306:3306 <some_azure_repository>/databasedump:<tag_number>
```

Then i try to connect to the database from the integration tests (written in Python)
And i get the following error:

```
+ 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

and i am wondering whether the Maria DB is successfully started.
How can i prove it from an Azure pipeline?

This problem is when i put the whole database dump in the Maria DB docker image. When i put only several tables from the dump in the image, everything works fine.

Comment: By default a MySQL installation only binds to 127.0.0.1 which would not be reachable from outside the container. Did you make sure to configure MariaDB to bind itself to all available IPs?

Comment: @RoderickBant I do not know how to make sure how to do what you advised. But 1.I connect to the database via python code using "localhost" as host 2.I added 2 minutes delay between the starting of the maria db docker container and the starting of the execution of the integration tests and now everything works fine.

Comment: 2 minutes does sound like a lot. You could run creating the database connection from python at 10 second intervals until it connects.